# Error para conectar JPA con base de datos MariaDB

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mariadb

Tengo una base de datos creada en MariaDB e intento conectarme utilizando JPA/Hibernate, pero me sale el siguiente error al ejecutar la aplicacion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Arquitectura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Persitencias:

```
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="persistencia" >
    <!--  Representació de les classes   -->
    <class>clases.Jugada</class>
    <class>clases.Jugador</class>
    <class>clases.Partida</class>
    <!--  Propietats de la connexió amb la BD  -->
    <properties>
      <!-- The JDBC driver of your database -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" />
      <!-- The JDBC URL to the database instance -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/torneo" />
      <!-- The database username -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
      <!-- The database password -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />

      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>

    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

POM.XML (Con las dependencias) - JPA - Hibernate - MariaDB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>eric</groupId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

App.java (Main) - Vi en la documentación que solo hacia falta esta linea para la conexión:

```
package clases;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.List;

public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {


        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistencia");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();

    }
}
```

He intentado mirar si el problema era de la version del JPA o Hibernate y nada, dado que el error me persiste en el Main sigo sin entender cual es el problema.

Comment: Por favor, añade el código como texto. Como imagen es difícil usarlo para ayudar

Comment: @Alfabravo Claro, perdona, ya lo actualice.

Comment: saludos te sugiero revisar esto: https://memorynotfound.com/mysql-mariadb-hibernate-annotation-configuration-example/

Comment: @Victor Matilla lo que muestras en la imagen del proyecto es la carpera **target** esa carpeta es la que utiliza maven para crear las clases compiladas del proyecto, podrías revisar si dentro de la ruta **src/main/java/META-INF/persistence.xml** tienes el archivo de persistencia.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran Si lo tengo

Comment: y es el mismo contenido que has mostrado aquí, porque pareciera que tienes un error en el los tags del XML en el archivo persistence.xml, para descartar esa posibilidad.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran Asi es, tiene el mismo contenido que el otro

Comment: En el xml tenés letras con acento, sacalos o reemplazalos por la letra sin acento a ver si es eso lo que te está rompiendo el xml.

Comment: @Juan Al ser comentario no tiene por que afectar, pero ya lo he quitado y el error persiste